# Django Rest Framework display reverse field

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

My question is around designing a RESTful API with Django Rest Framework. I have the following two data files.

```
# cars.csv
Escalade, Ford
Outback, Subaru
Fiesta, Ford

# description.csv
new, "Escalade", 2018, "perfect condition"
used, "Escalade", 2016, "in good shape"
used, "Escalade", 2010, "bad condition"
```

I want a GET-only API endpoint that would output the following:

```
{
  "model": "Escalade",
  "company": "Ford",
  "year": 2018,
  "details": [
    {
      "condition": "new",
      "description": "perfect condition"
    }
 ]
```

}

The issue is how to display `year` so it is displayed up a level from its model position. If I changed the original csv files I could add year to cars.csv but assume I can't do that. How would I configure my serializer to output the desired API endpoint?

This is the model, serializer, view, and url.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Detail(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', related_name='details',
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models


class DetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('year', 'condition', 'description',)
        model = models.Detail


class CarSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    details = DetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    fields = ('model', 'company', 'details',)
    model = models.Car

# views.py
from rest_framework import generics

from . import models
from . import serializers


class CarDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = models.Detail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DetailSerializer


class CarList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CarSerializer



# urls.py 
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CarList.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>', views.CarDetail.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps use a `SerializerMethodField`.

```or-tag-here
class CarSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    details = DetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    year = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('model', 'company', 'details', 'year',)
        model = models.Car

    def get_year(self, car):
        return car.details.first().year
```

You need to be a little bit careful, as the above example assumes that there will always be at least one `Detail` for a car, and it will use the first it finds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please note I slightly modified the original code so the `Description` table is now `Detail`. I see the wisdom of your approach however I'm stuck with a `AttributeError at / 'Car' object has no attribute 'detail_set'`. It should be able to do the reverse lookup on `detail_set` in the `get_year` method so I'm not sure.

Comment: Also I think the workaround you note suggests that perhaps the better choice is simply to update the original csv files, if at all possible, vs trying to implement this kind of reverse. Yeah?

Comment: Ah yes, the foreign key has a `related_name` of `details` - I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: But yes, it does highlight the fact that perhaps the datamodel isn't quite right - and moving `year` to `Car` may be a better approach.